# Implement object-fit in C# for email templates

Tags: c#, html-email, razor-pages, html-templates

I am working on a html template to send emails to users. The template can have images with different sizes and they can be different for every email. We want to fit every image into `120px X 90px` size but since outlook doesn't support css properties like `object-fit` and it makes the images look either strected(small images) or squashed(large images) due to fixed height property. If remove the height property, it affects the overall design.

Can someone suggest on implementing the css property `object-fit:contain` in c# to make the image fit in `120px X 90px` (4:3 ratio) or using outlook css properties?

Example :
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_object-fit_all

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am using C# razor engine to generate emails.

Update #1:
Outook hacks/solutions are not helping. Can someone suggest how to clip a base64 encoded image to maintain its aspect ratio(4:3) while fitting withing the image frame(`120px X 90px`)?

Comment: Use MDN as a reference, not W3Schools. As the name says, W3Schools is just tutorials. MDN on the other hand is the de-facto reference site for HTML, CSS and JavaScript supported by all browser vendors. The docs and tutorials there are far better too. The [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) entry shows it's not supported by IE11. Which browser do your clients use? If it's Outlook, it may be IE11

Comment: There are sites that show CSS rule compatibility for various email clients. `object-fit` support is patchy, and doesn't work at all in Outlook, Outlook.com, Yahoo email.

Comment: Can you clarify whether these images MUST be 120x90, and/or whether you need these clipped, or whether you just want width to always = 120, perhaps, and set the height to auto? I.e. what are the requirements in detail?

Comment: @Nathan I want to clip the image to 120x90

Comment: and must have this size

Comment: so tell us more about the images themselves---are they already in an aspect ratio of 4:3 (in which case a height=90, width=120, as attributes, would surely work)? Or are they all over the place (requiring dynamic clipping)?

Comment: they can be of any size. We want to crop the center of the images after scaling down.

Answer (score 0):

It has been over five years since I worked on a similar task to create templated e-mails (including images) using an embedded Razor engine in my C# application, so I cannot remember the details anymore.

I do remember that e-mail styling cannot be compared to webpage styling at all; CSS support among e-mail client software is terrible.

Perhaps you can try to use the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<img>` element instead of (or in addition to) trying to use CSS here?

**Edit:**

I found some old test files from five years ago. Back then, I did indeed set the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<img>` element, and I also used the following CSS properties in an inline `style` attribute:

```
max-width: 120px;
max-height: 90px;
display: inline !important;
```

So, apart from any additional attributes and styling properties, an image tag would look something like this:

```
<img src="<your image location here>" width="120" height="90" style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 90px; display: inline !important" />
```

I haven't tested it now, but I hope this can work for you.

**Edit 2:**

I noticed that I also used a self-closing `<img>` tag in my old test file, because I declared the document type as XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I fixed my previous code accordingly. Sorry about that.